# download option to work in offline - Android

Tags: android

Am Working in an Exam application App. In that questions are retrived from backend via JSON. Only issue am facing now is incase if there is no network means the app is not working. Is it possible to set an download option so that user can download and write the questions whenever they need and post it when there is network. Is it possible to set an download option to download the activites?

Comment: You can download the JSON and store locally and refresh it when the network is available.

Comment: you need to store those data in mobile when app is connected to internet.<br>
Store ques and ans by user  in sqlite with flag to check whether it is updated live or not. you cannot download when you are offline :)

Answer (score 0):

The logic I want to recommend you to do is

Make user to write question in edittext.
Save that question in database with one more extra column "Sync" which is false.
The when internet is available fetch all the question which has synced column value as false (which means question is not synced in internet)and  send that object via JSON. After success response,
set that Sync value for that question to True which means that the question is synced with internet.